# How to monitor windows GPU in zabbix

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, zabbix-agent, gpu

I am using zabbix 6.0 and I wan to monitor the gpu usage and temperature and other things related to GPU of my windows host, How can I do that, I have windows 10 and agent installed

Comment: Find a command line tool that shows you the desired values; configure the command in the Zabbix Agent; configure the check in Zabbix Server.

Comment: Thanks Gerald, got it, used nividia smi , one more thing , I want to see all the application installed in the host, how can I do that.